# Defining a time range for aggregation in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got an index in ElasticSearch with documents having info about user connections to my platform. I want to build a query with day aggregation where I can count all users connected every day between two given dates.

I have 3 relevant fields to do so: `user_id`, `connection_time_start`, `connection_time_end`. I was doing the query this way:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "connection_time_start": {
              "lte": "2017-08-04T23:59:59"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "connection_time_end": {
              "gte": "2017-08-02T00:00:00"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "franja_horaria": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "connection_time_start",
        "interval": "day",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "ids": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "user_id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query has given as a result buckets containing the number of users that had the starting connection at day 2, 3 & 4 of August. The problem is that there are users with connections starting on day 2 and ending on day 3 and even on day 4.

These users should compute for the connected user count for each day but as I'm doing the aggregation with the connection_time_start only counts for that day.

I've tried to add a range in the aggregation some thing like this(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/search-aggregations-bucket-daterange-aggregation.html) but haven't got a good result.

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like a data issue and not like a query issue... Please explain what your data looks like.

Comment: Hi Mickael, there is some info about users in every doc but the important the important fields are the ones I mentined before:

user_id wich is just an integer,
connection_time_start: wich is a dateTime field &
connection_time_end wich is a dateTime field too